# sizeof array clarification

Tags: c

I am studying for a final tomorrow in C, and have a question regarding the sizeof operator.

Let's say the size of an `int` is `32` bits and a pointer is `64` bits.

If there were a function:

```
int
foo (int zap[])
{
    int a = sizeof(zap);
    return a;
}
```

Because `zap` is a pointer, `foo` would return `8`, as that's how many bytes are needed to store this particular pointer. However, with the following code:

```
int zip[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int i = sizeof(zip);
```

`i` would be `6 * sizeof(int)` = `6 * 4` = `24`

Why is it that `sizeof(zip)` returns the number of elements times the size of each element, whereas `sizeof(zap)` returns the size of a pointer? Is it that the size of `zap` is unspecified, and `zip` is not? The compiler *knows* that `zip` is `6` elements, but doesn't have a clue as to how large `zap` may be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is sort of an asymmetry in the C syntax. In C it's not possible to pass an array to a function, so when you use the array syntax in a function declaration for one of the parameters the compiler instead reads it as a pointer.

In C in most cases when you use an array in an expression the array is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element and that is exactly what happens for example when you call a function. In the following code:

```
int bar[] = {1,2,3,4};
foo(bar);
```

the array is converted to a pointer to the first element and that is what the function receives.

This rule of implict conversion is not however always applied. As you discovered for example the `sizeof` operator works on the array, and even `&` (address-of) operator works on the original array (i.e. `sizeof(*&bar) == 4*sizeof(int)`).

A function in C cannot recevive an array as parameter, it can only receive a pointer to the first element, or a pointer to an array... or you must wrap the array in a structure.

Even if you put a number between the brackets in the function declaration...

```
void foo(int x[4])
{
    ...
}
```

that number is completely ignored by the compiler... that declaration for the compiler is totally equivalent to

```
void foo(int *x)
{
    ...
}
```

and for example even calling it passing an array with a different size will not trigger any error...

```
int tooshort[] = {1,2,3};
foo(tooshort);  /* Legal, even if probably wrong */
```

(actually a compiler *MAY* give a warning, but the code is perfectly legal C and must be accepted if the compiler follows the standard)

If you think that this rule about arrays when in function arguments is strange then I agree, but this is how the C language is defined.

Comment: The number is not ignored by the compiler, int x[4] as a function parameter means that you must pass an array pointer of _exactly_ 4 elements. It is the very same thing as writing `int (*x)[4]` elsewhere in the code. Apart from that, this answer points out the problem: array syntax for parameters has a different meaning to arrays declared elsewhere in the program. It is one of the dumber "features" of the C language. To avoid confusion, always use the `int* x` notation for parameters.

Comment: Can you point where its written in the standard that the number between brackets must be equal to the size of the passed array? Hint: this would be a strange requirment given that you cannot pass an array at all and that the function actually receives just a pointer. When calling a function with `foo(bar)` where `bar` is an array that array has already been converted to a pointer **even for the compiler** before the function call is considered. It would make no sense to impose a limitation on a size information that has been already dropped in the conversion.

Comment: @Lundin, no for the first dimension of array parameters the 4 is essentially ignored. C99 has possibility for the keyword `static` in addition, there, to specify that the function expects *at least* for items. But still the type of the parameter is `int*`.

Comment: After checking the standard C99 6.7.5.3 §7 it would seem that the size of the array pointer only matters if the parameter is declared static. All of it is really obscure, and I don't believe C90 had this "feature". Best practice is to never ever use [] for function parameters, then you don't need to wonder what the C committee were smoking when they wrote this particular part of the standard.

Comment: Thank you 6502 this helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Because zip is an **array** and the compiler knows its size at **compile-time**. It just a case of using the same notation for two different things, something quite usual in C.

```
int
foo (int zap[])
```

is completely equivalent to

```
int
foo (int *zap)
```

The compiler doesn't have any idea how big zap could be (so it leaves the task of finding out to the programmer).

Comment: Even if you put a number between the brackets however that is still just a pointer and the number itself is completely ignored by the compiler. So its not a problem about the compiler not knowing the size... its that the C language has a special strange rule about arrays in function argument lists.

Comment: @6502 You are correct, good call. Putting a number in the brackets will have the same effect, which is why it's strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

`zip` is a memory block of `6 * sizeof(int)` so it has a size of 24 (on your architecture).
`zap` (it could be also written as `int *zap` in your function declaration) however can point to any memory address and the compiler has no way of knowing how much space starting at this (or even containing this) address has been allocated.

Answer (score 0):

The size of `zip` is known at compile time and the size of `zap` is not.  That is why you are getting the size of a pointer on `sizeof(zap)` and the size of the array on `sizeof(zip)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some situations wherearrays decay to pointers. Function calls is one of those.

Answer (score -1):

because it has been statically initialized with 6 elemens.

Comment: someone wish to clarify downvote? My answer is the same as the 2 others, just a little more succinct ??

Comment: I didn't do the downvote, but it really doesn't matter if "zip" was initialized or not. The issue is all about C's weird function parameter syntax.