# Different c array declaration

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sizeof array clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933255/sizeof-array-clarification)

I have 2 arrays declared

`GLfloat gCubeVertexData[216] = { list of numbers};`

and an array declared:

```
GLfloat *resultArray = malloc(sizeof(GLfloat) * [arrayOfVerticies count]);

    for(int i = 0; i < [arrayOfVerticies count]; i++)
    {
        resultArray[i] = [[arrayOfVerticies objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];

    }
```

why is it when I do `sizeof(gCubeVertexData)` I get 864 ( a GLflot is 4 bits so divided by 4 and you get 216)

and when I do `sizeof(resultArray)` I get 4? event though if I were to print out resultArray[100] I get the correct number, and there is a lot more than 4 numbers stored?

Comment: sizeof(resultArray) returns the Size of a pointer. i.e. on 32 bit system its 4 bytes.

Comment: cheers, don't know how i missed that (schoolboy error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `gCubeVertexData` is an array, and `resultArray` is a pointer. In the case of an array, the compiler knows how many bytes it is required to allocate for the array, so it explicitly knows a size (in the case of variable-length arrays in C99, it can also be computed easily at runtime, perhaps by messing with the stack pointer).

However, in the case of `malloc()`, the compiler has no knowledge about the size of the memory pointed by the pointer (that size can be obtained in a non-standard and platform-dependent way only anyways...), so it just returns the size of the **variable** itself, which is a pointer in this case, so you'll get back `sizeof(GLfloat *)` in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Because with `sizeof(resultArray)` you are getting the size of the pointer to the first element.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `resultArray` is simply `GLfloat *`, i.e. "pointer to `GLfloat`, and your machine uses 4 characters to store a pointer. The size information associated with the pointer is not visible to the `sizeof` operator.

Therefore, `sizeof resultArray == sizeof (GLfloat *)`, which is what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the declaration of gCubeVertexData and resultArray. The first is an array with 216 elements, the latter is just a pointer. C (and thus C++ and Objective-C) allow to use pointers to access arrays, but that does not mean they have the same type.