# Someone can explain this?

Tags: c, printf, sizeof

I really dont understand this.Maybe someone can explain me .
I wanted find out how many elements is in dataInput. I'm programming in C

```
void Calibrate_data(float* dataInput)
{   
    int dataSize = sizeof(*dataInput)/sizeof(float);
    printf("%i and %i",sizeof(*dataInput)/sizeof(float),dataSize);
}
```

The output is:

```
1 and 10
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933255/sizeof-array-clarification

Comment: Plesae print a newline after the second value so that we can rule out that the output is as we expect, just with a spurious `0` tacked on somewhere else. (Not very likely, but still.)

Comment: Ran your code, can't reproduce your output. I got `1 and 1`. My first guess is what @MOehm suggested, a `0` printed somewhere else following this. Include a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that compiles/runs and demonstrates the error.

Comment: Please, please, give your question a decent title that summarizes the question subject.

Comment: Curious if you have tried adding a `\n` to the printf to see if that changes the output from `10` to `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the wrong format specifier here:

```
printf("%i and %i",sizeof(*dataInput)/sizeof(float),dataSize);
        ^^
```

`sizeof` returns `size_t` type which is *unsigned* the correct format specifier is `%zu` or `%Iu` in Visual Studio.

Using the wrong format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) but that does not seem to explain the output of `10` for `dataSize` which does not make sense since `sizeof(*dataInput)` will be the size of a `float`. So we would expect `sizeof(*dataInput)/sizeof(float)` to be `1`, as Macattack said an SSCCE should help resolve that output.

Answer (score 2):

When pass the array to function it will decay to pointer. You cannot calculate the size of the pointer, so sizeof will not give the number of element. If you want you can pass the array size as the arguments to the function.

Here `*dataInput` is the first element, It is float type . So `sizeof(*dataInput)` mean that `sizeof(float)`.

`sizeof(*dataInput)/sizeof(float) = 4/4 = 1;`

Example Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void Calibrate_data(float* dataInput);
int main()
{
    float data[] = { 12.22, 15.15 };
    Calibrate_data(data);
    return 0;
}

void Calibrate_data(float *dataInput)
{   
    printf("float size : %zu %zu\n", sizeof(*dataInput), sizeof(float));
    int dataSize = sizeof(*dataInput)/sizeof(float);
    printf("%zu and %d\n",sizeof(*dataInput)/sizeof(float),dataSize);
}
```

Output:

```
float size : 4 4
1 and 1
```

**EDIT:**
Output `10` might be the wrong usage of format specifer or output may be '1' that '0' printed from somewhere else. Because he not added newline character at end of the printf so we cannot assure that last `0` associated with this printf.

Comment: And where does 10 come from?

Comment: @herohuyongtao That might be the wrong usage of format specifer or it maybe printed from somewhere else, Because he not added newline character at end of the `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a problem with a 64-bit platform that uses 32-bit `int` and 64-bits for `size_t` (the type of `sizeof`'s result).

In this scenario

```
printf("%i and %i",sizeof(*dataInput)/sizeof(float),dataSize);
         ^      ^  -------------------------------- --------
         |      |                  ^                    ^
         |      |                  |                    +---- 32-bit operand
         |      |                  +--- 64-bit operand
         |      |
         |      +--- expects 32-bit operand
         |
         +--- expects 32-bit operand
```

The mismatch in conversion specifiers and operands results in undefined behavior.

One of the following should fix the problem:

```
printf("%i and %i",(int) (sizeof(*dataInput)/sizeof(float)),dataSize);  // cast size_t type to int


// as mentioned by Shafik Yaghmour in his answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21266299/12711

// this might not be supported on compilers that don't claim C99 support, 
//  for example, MSVC docs indicate that "I" should be used instead of "z" for size_t types

printf("%zu and %i",sizeof(*dataInput)/sizeof(float),dataSize);  // C99 - use correct conversion spec
printf("%Iu and %i",sizeof(*dataInput)/sizeof(float),dataSize);  // MSVC - use 'correct' conversion spec
```

Comment: I thought this could be an explanation but I can not reproduce on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) which fits this scenario using either `gcc` or `clang`, although once we are talking about undefined behavior that does not mean much.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: I also have trouble reproducing the exact output, but in this case what get's output probably depends on what happens to be on some memory location on the stack or in a register half that's otherwise not explicitly set to 0 (or something). I think the OP will get the expected output once the `printf()` is fixed.